# Find All References of view in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, model-view-controller

How can I find which function refers to desired view
e.g

I have view 'Cricket' and it's being called from following locations:

```
1-AddCricket function in HomeController
2-ViewCricket function in HomeController
3-ListCrickete function in Controller
```

How can I find above information

**I am talking about like 'Find All Reference' that appears when I right click on any function**

Comment: Rename your class, compile, and watch the errors come in =)

Comment: @Tung. Actually he needs to rename the **view** name, use (new version of)resharper, finally watch the errors coming in...

Comment: @gdoron Yeah I would have suggested Resharper :).  Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @Tung "home/cricket/?page=125" Also this type of syntax is written code,Your solution will fail in this case

Answer (score 1):

The only way is:

`Ctrl +f` => search for: `return View("Cricket"`

Comment: sleazy if effective

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Find window, choose (Current Project) , 
and search for :

1- `ActionResult Cricket(`

2- `return View("Cricket"`

3- `RenderPartial("Cricket"`

Comment: your solution don't guarantee of 100% result,sometime the following syntax is used in code like "home/cricket/?page=125"

Answer (score 1):

You could use [T4MVC](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=T4MVC_doc&referringTitle=T4MVC), it generates dummy classes for you to use your views, controllers and even links to js and css files strongly typed.

Like this:

```
return View(Views.Cricket);
```

See more examples [here on codeplex](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=T4MVC_doc&referringTitle=T4MVC) or get it from [Nuget](http://nuget.org/packages/T4MVC).

You can even do:

```
@Html.RenderPartial(MVC.Views.Cricket)
```

And the following, calls the `Create` method on the `CricketController`:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create Cricket Page", MVC.Cricket.Create())
```